# How to Configure Service Fabric with two stateless service on different port

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I have a stateless service, Subscription Service.
Subscription Service has 3 routes(3 controllers)

- "api/v1/Subscription"
- "api/v1/notification"
- "api/v1/AdminService".

Now I want to add new service BotService, on port 9067. it has 1 route "api/v1/botservice" How to configure Service Fabric to route calls to Bot Service for its registered routes and Subscription Service on its registered route.

Comment: You want to call all services on the same port? Or what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

If each service runs on a different port then there shouldn't be a problem. You need to update your cluster network resources (NSG and load balancer) to enable inbound traffic towards your cluster VMSS, on the new port (9067).

Answer (score 0):

this links can be maybe helpful:
https://dzimchuk.net/hosting-multiple-externally-accessible-asp-net-core-applications-in-service-fabric/
or this:
https://dzimchuk.net/exposing-services-on-different-domains-in-azure-service-fabric/